# Assign variable subdirectory to output command in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to implement shell script to get the list of files of subdirectory:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/Movies"
MOVIES=${PWD}${PATH}
LS="$(ls -lp) ${MOVIES}"
```

But I'm getting this error:
ls: command not found

How can add the subdirectory to the ls command? I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

in setting a PATH variable in your script, you have overwritten the default PATH variable that tells your shell where your common binaries are located. Either change your PATH variable name, or use the full ls path '/bin/ls'

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/Movies"
MOVIES=${PWD}${PATH}
LS="/bin/ls -lp ${MOVIES}"

$LS
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
NOTPATH="/Movies"
MOVIES=${PWD}${NOTPATH}
LS="ls -lp ${MOVIES}"

$LS
```

more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167454/basic-commands-in-unix-not-working-i-e-bash-ls-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I tried your example but this the output I'm getting "ls -lp /Users/myUser/Movies"

Comment: what is your desired output? when used in my shell (Ubuntu 16.04)  both list the contents of the directory as expected. do you mean that the script echoes the command and does not execute it?

Comment: The output I want is the list of files in that directory

Comment: hmm, try preceding the final line with eval, so that it would read:

eval $LS

Comment: when using [an online bash script tool](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online) with [this code](https://gist.github.com/primordialTruth/0f29063e8c9db9e696ad1d12570eab60#file-test-sh), both
`$TEST` and `eval $TEST` yield the same results; the script prints the directory contents twice.

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good idea to not use UPPERCASE variables in shell scripts, as they're the default pattern for system wide environment variables. This way you will avoid overwriting some variable with your own. If you must, run the `env` command to see what variables are set in your bash session.